# issues with projection Rgdal versus Manifold

Tags: coordinate-system, r, rgdal, manifold

I am pretty new to the topic and OK with R, but spatial data is still terra incognita

I got a Mapinfo file and i had to convert it to ESRI shp and then within r into spatial lines data frame and use with leaflet+OS maps epsg:3857

whatever i tried within R with spTransform (rgdal) it did not work - either was not visible or was visible with offset (approx 20 meters). Proj4 did not want to work with SLDF.
I took the file into Manifold, converted it to 3857, returned to R, transformed it to epsg:4269 and it works perfectly OK with leaflet + OS map 3857. But i have to automate this process to work within R, without any Manifold intervention.

I checked how the files differed:
i selected one item (the same of course) from the file and to make it easy to present created a centroid for it. Then I checked projection, xy, and latlong.

the item created from the file without using Manifold:
proj4string

```
"+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs"
```

centroid:

```
528685 181836.2
```

centroid after spTransform to 4269

```
-0.1450149 51.52028
```

the item from the file pre-processed by Manifold:
proj4string

```
"+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +units=m +no_defs"
```

centroid:

```
-16321.64 6713938
```

centroid after spTransform to 4269:

```
-0.1466198 51.52079
```

the latter is correct of course. Just to emphasize - it is the same file and the same item

Few questions:

1. any idea what happens in Manifold that fails in rgdal?
2. is there any mechanism in R that I can apply to fix the error (to match the 'with Manifold' output)? Maybe a kind of offset or work on prj files?

I tried to use the latter CRS for transformation

```
P5 <-spTransform(ptp.points1P, CRS( "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +units=m +no_defs"))
```

and it returned still incorrect values
the xy is t least inverted but shifted

```
 -16142.98 6713847
```

the latlong is of course incorrect, but the same as without any attempt to transform

```
-0.1450149 51.52028
```

content of prj file not transformed - failing to correctly show

```
PROJCS["Transverse_Mercator",GEOGCS["GCS_Airy 1830",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["airy",6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",49],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-2],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996012717],PARAMETER["false_easting",400000],PARAMETER["false_northing",-100000],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

content of prj manifold transformed file - good to go

```
PROJCS["Mercator_2SP",GEOGCS["GCS_unnamed ellipse",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["Unknown",6378137,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Mercator"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Comment: Note: you should not be converting to 4269, but 4326. 4269 is NAD83--used in North America. 4326 is WGS 84.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: there was just one question, the other statement was a pre-requisite to answer THE question - "how can i replicate the transformation Manifold did without manifold". The answer is below - by substituting the proj4 content. I truly do not see what broad is about it. Mkennedy - probably it was another Manifold pitfall that was rectified by removing the proj4. But believe me, the NA transformation worked for London data;)

Answer (score 1):

seems I found the answer
with the file not processed i swapped the proj4str to bng (without transformation, just a swap)

```
bng = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs'
```

and then the file worked like the Manifold
I have no idea how the manifold swapped the strings in the first place, but at least I know how to automate it